# Is it possible to create referring column / foreign keys in same table

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, foreign-keys

I hope I explain this as clear as needed.
I would like to create a column referring to a different column in the same table, while both these columns aren't PK's and the first(existing column) isn't a FK yet, just a column. The second one does not exist. The table already exist and has data.

Existing situation example:
TABLE Equipment
PK '*EquipmentID*'
Column '*External ID*' (nvarchar(50) null)

Desired situation example:
TABLE Equipment
PK *EquipmentID*
Column '*ExternalID*' (nvarchar(50) null)
Column '*Partof '**ExternalID***''

Thanks in advance!

Literal example:
Equipment ID : 1
Equipment Description : washing machine
External ID : ABC

Equipment ID : 2
Equipment Description : Pump
External ID : NULL
PartofExternalID : ABC

Comment: Should `partofexternalid` show a substring of `externalid`? Or how is this supposed to look?

Comment: It's not at all clear what you are asking. Are you after a *computed column*?

Comment: @Robert edit your question and add the clarity to it, not as a comment.

Comment: @Robert: You can [edit] a question to add examples. That's more readable than in comments.

Answer (score 2):

From what I get, you want a foreign key referencing a unique column in the table itself.

```
CREATE TABLE equipment
             (equipmentid integer,
              externalid nvarchar(50),
              partof nvarchar(50),
              PRIMARY KEY (equipmentid),
              UNIQUE (externalid),
              FOREIGN KEY (partof)
                          REFERENCES equipment
                                     (externalid));
```

Though I wonder why you want to do that via that "external" ID? Consider just using the "internal" one.

---

Edit:

If the columns already exist, you can use following `ALTER` statement.

```
ALTER TABLE equipment
            ADD UNIQUE (externalid),
                FOREIGN KEY (partof)
                            REFERENCES equipment
                                       (externalid);
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! Unfortunatelly it did not work. I had to the the 'CREATE' to an 'ALTER' as the table did already exist.
The program that uses the database needs to insert data from an Excel file, with these relations (externalId & PartofEId.) already in them. The program creates the EquipmentID automatically. So I tried to create the FKey link in the database and therefore the program, meaning I wouldn't have to change everything by hand :)

Comment: @Robert: "it did not work" isn't really much to work on... Elaborate.

Comment: Sorry. As you might have seen by my question, answers and formulation, I'm a bit of a SQL noob.
The above standing script just gave me an "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'UNIQUE'." Tried with and without the brackets. Also without the PK Line, as that was already established. Anyhow, I think I'll just have to bite through and fill in manually

Comment: @Robert: Well, I did test it and there's no syntax error in the `CREATE`. I also edited in an `ALTER` for you. And well, according to this [test](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=f07ba13b16aac8927ddc4a690c511ea2) both work fine.

Answer (score -1):

1- To set an existing column as PK, it's data must be unique and not null, so in table designer you can set it as PK and save it, it's done if that condition satisfied.

2- Again, to set an existing column as referring (FK) to another column, its data must be a subset of the reference column. You can easily set the relation in designer and save it, then see the result.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The first column that the second should refer to is not the PK, but should be made an FK. As some of the data does not have a relation, that should be able to have a null.